# SAXParseException: Element type "CountryNamecode" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: java, xml, sax, jaxp

OK, this seems like a common error message, but I've looked at this from a few angles, and I'm stumped.

My XML (complete file is huge, so limiting to area that seems related unless somebody can tell me how/why I need more here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyXML date="201112102200" type="daily">
    <CountryList>
        <CountryName code="AARCT" name="Antarctica" IsTerritory="True"/>
        <CountryName code="ABKHAZ" name="Abkhazia" IsTerritory="True"/>

        <!-- ... -->

        <CountryName code="VCAN" name="Vatican City" IsTerritory="False" ProfileURL="vatican city.doc"/>
        <CountryName code="VEN" name="Venezuela" IsTerritory="False" ProfileURL="venezuela.doc"/>
        <CountryName code="VI" name="US Virgin Islands" IsTerritory="True"/>
        <CountryName code="VIETN" name="Vietnam" IsTerritory="False" ProfileURL="vietnam.doc"/>
        <CountryName code="WALLIS" name="Wallis and Futuna Islands" IsTerritory="True"/>
        <CountryName code="WSOMOA" name="Samoa" IsTerritory="False" ProfileURL="samoa.doc"/>
        <CountryName code="YEMAR" name="Yemen" IsTerritory="False" ProfileURL="yemen.doc"/>
        <CountryName code="YUG" name="Serbia" IsTerritory="False" ProfileURL="serbia.doc"/>
        <CountryName code="ZAIRE" name="Democratic Republic of the Congo" IsTerritory="False" ProfileURL="democratic republic of the congo.doc"/>
        <CountryName code="ZAMBIA" name="Zambia" IsTerritory="False" ProfileURL="zambia.doc"/>
        <CountryName code="ZIMBAB" name="Zimbabwe" IsTerritory="False" ProfileURL="zimbabwe.doc"/>
    </CountryList>

    <!-- ... -->

</MyXML>
```

So the error is:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "CountryNamecode" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1231)
    at com.foo.bar.Baz.<init>(Baz.java:38)
    at com.foo.bar.BazTest.testRecordCounts(BazTest.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

The logging I have indicated it's failing after country code "VI", and that there's something wrong with the "VIETN" entry.

So, there doesn't appear to be a malformed element called "CountryNamecode", I've checked for dodgy characters, but it's all pretty vanilla character-wise. The whole file validates when I've checked it, using STS, Oxygen, and xmllint.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers folks!

EDIT:

```
XMLReader xmlReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
xmlReader.setContentHandler(this);
xmlReader.setErrorHandler(this);
xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(retriever.getContent())));
```

The retriever object is returning the xml string, and other than that, I'm parsing an InputSource, passing it the StringReader. Unless there's something obvious I'm missing

Comment: Sounds like a missing space between `CountryName` and the `code` attribute in the xml source.

Comment: Was slightly more hidden than that, it was the reading of the string from the source file (as in answer below) but cheers for the suggestion, you were kind-of right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be prepared to bet the issue is in the underlying data stream code.

To support my theory, open the original data file, move the cursor to the space between `CountryName` and `code` and find a way of determining the exact offset of that space character in the file. It is likely to be an exact multiple of 1024 and probably 4096 or 8192.

Then look at the `InputSource` or `Reader` code you are using to feed the SAX parser. It will probably look something like:

```
sax = factory.newSAXParser();
try {
  // Here I am using an InputSource wrapping a StringReader.
  sax.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)), this);
} catch (SAXException ex) {
  log.warning("XMLParser failed on: "+xml, ex);
}
```

I suspect whatever you are using instead of the `new InputSource(new StringReader(xml))` I use above is what is corrupting the data.

Comment: Hi OldCurmudgeon, this does look very plausible, although my code isn't vastly different, added code snippet to Question.

Comment: @pocon64 - From your edit I would suggest investigating `retriever.getContent()` to see what it does between buffers.

Comment: Bullseye, I was trimming the string while I was appending it. Cheers!